# Question about String operations in Python

Tags: python, string, list, split, slice

I am new to Python, and was practising File Operations. I have written this program:

```
myfile = open('test3.txt', 'w+')
myfile.writelines(['Doctor', 'Subramanian', 'Swamy', 'Virat', 'Hindustan', 'Sangam'])
```

which outputs the following:
`DoctorSubramanianSwamyViratHindustanSangam`.

How do I add spaces in between items of the list in the final output such that the final output is `Doctor Subramanian Swamy Virat Hindustan Sangam`?

Comment: If your list is `['Doctor', 'Subramanian', 'Swamy', 'Virat', 'Hindustan', 'Sangam']`, then the quotes are not part of the content; they're just delineating the strings. What output are you trying to get?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understood from your question, you wish to add spaces between elements of the list in the final output. One possible solution is:

```
myfile = open('test3.txt', 'w+')
list = ['Doctor', 'Subramanian', 'Swamy', 'Virat', 'Hindustan', 'Sangam']
for l in list:
    myfile.write(l+' ')
```

In particular, this line `myfile.write(l+' ')` will add a space after writing every element.

Answer (score -1):

You could try stripping it using the same .strip() method?

```
value = "'"

list1 = []

for item in list2:
    list1.append(item.strip("{0}".format(value)))
```

try it and let me know